# Borrar elementos repetidos

Tags: repetidos

tengo mi codigo donde busco eliminar por completo los elementos repetidos de un array pero me sale completamente lo opuesto en donde me estoy equivocando? muchas gracias.

```
 function destruye(arr){
   return arr.filter(function(item, index, array) {
    return arr.indexOf(item) !== index;
    })
  }
```

destruye([1,1,3,5,6,1,3])

//me tendria que devolver [5,6]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a [ES.so] por favor lee [ask] y haz el [tour], también te recomiendo leer como hacer un [example], las preguntas tipo tengo que hacer esto sin codigo de lo probado suelen terminar cerradas debido a falta de trabajo de investigación, recuerda que esta plataforma es para ayudarte con problemas puntuales de codigo, no para hacer tu tarea o trabajo, por ultimo, siempre recuerda investigar por tu parte, con el simple hecho de poner "eliminar objetos repetidos array javascript" en google ya tendrás a disposición cientos de ejemplos a tu alcance.

Comment: Q lenguaje de programacion?

Comment: La expresión que calcula el valor retornado en su función obtiene los elementos repetidos. Almacénela en una variable local "rwpwtidos" de la función y retorne los elementos del array que no existen en el arreglo "repetidos"

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Mauricio